# Subset-ing. Created/cleaned new variables in a data frame; when I subset, not in the new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, wherein I've created new variables (which are 'cleaned' versions of the originals). When I subset the data frame, these new variables don't seem to be in the subsetted data frame.  Do I need to create these new variables again? Or is there a way to ensure that they are in the subsetted data frame.

A little more detail: I have 'attach'-ed a data frame 'x'.

```
newdf <- subset (x, (income %in% c('<20000')))
```

(Income is cleaned version of another variable, and is a factor variable.) 
So the new data frame should contain only those with income less than 20000.

This seems to work, and does, indeed give me a new data frame with the correct number of observations.

However, when I try to do

```
freq (newdf$income)
```

I get:

> Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) : 
>     need finite 'xlim' values
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In min(w.l) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(w.r) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>   3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Please post a dataset example using `dput(head(data, 20))`. And sample code, like this it's impossible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `table()` function to check frequency or count of `income` in the new subsetted data frame.

As far as I understand you want to subset your dataset having just one of the levels of `income` variable i.e. `<20000` in the `newdf` and then checking no. of observations with income `<20000` in the `newdf`

Implementing same in `iris` dataset

```
dim(iris)
# [1] 150   5  

table(iris$Species)

# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     50         50         50 


newdf <- subset(iris, Species %in% "virginica")
dim(newdf)
# [1] 50  5

table(newdf$Species)

# setosa versicolor  virginica 
#      0          0         50
```

---

**Another Example**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:9, b = as.factor(rep(c("<100","<200", "<300"), each = 3)))
df
#   a    b
# 1 1 <100
# 2 2 <100
# 3 3 <100
# 4 4 <200
# 5 5 <200
# 6 6 <200
# 7 7 <300
# 8 8 <300
# 9 9 <300

table(df$b)

# <100 <200 <300 
#    3    3    3 

newdf <- subset(df, b %in% "<300")
newdf
#   a    b
# 7 7 <300
# 8 8 <300
# 9 9 <300

table(newdf$b)

# <100 <200 <300 
#    0    0    3
```

Comment: dim (x) #original dataframe

> [1]10364  1086



    dim(newdf) #new data frame, created correctly & has right dimensions

>[1] 2301 1086

    table (newdf$income)

But then I get this: 

> < table of extent 0 >

Comment: please check if `income` exists as one of the column names in newdf or see if any typo..

Comment: It essentially seems like the variables that were in the original data frame, are fine in the NEW data frame, but the variables that I created, are not.

Comment: Updated with another example, see where you have it wrong or see if you have read data incorrectly?